# What is the term for an LCD readout that is, by design, still visible after power-off?

Tags: lcd

I am looking to build an electronic device that has an LCD panel on it with a feature I noticed my Western Digital MyBook external hard drive has which is the ability to display data and it stays visible after power-off. I suppose this is probably the same tech that e-book readers use, come to think of it. But if I were to start shopping around for some programmable components, what is this called?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WD harddrives use E Ink. E Ink is a type of Electronic Paper display created and produced by E Ink Co. It's one of the most well known and popular types. So much that people often refer to all electronic paper displays as E Ink (Similar to how iPod/iPhone, Google, and Photoshop are commonly used to refer to any similar product, however wrongly)

Comment: To be specific, those drives use an electrophoretic e-ink display.

Comment: @ConnorWolf thats two types of redundant. E Ink is a trade name for E Ink Co's electronic paper display, like plexiglas is to acrylic. E Ink also means electrophoretic ink. And E Ink Co. created and owns electrophoretic displays. PIN Number, ATM Machine, etc.

Comment: "E-Ink" **has become** somewhat of a colloquial term for electronic paper displays *in general*. This is a process call the *genericization* of a word. Anyways, there are a lot of other "e-ink" *style* displays out there that use different technologies: cholesteric LCDs, electrowetting, interferometric, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Passerby's answer. E-ink is a type of display that makes different tradeoffs. It is primarily designed for low power and as you mentioned, can retain its last image for long periods of time. However, you tradeoff refresh rate. So, it is suitable for books where the rate of change can be quite a long time (reading a page), but not for animations.